# Side Menu Within MapView XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

How do I add a functioning side menu that is within a map like Uber when you open it? I want to be able to click the "side menu" which displays the options. The main thing I am having trouble i being able to "drag" the menu to collapse it, like the homepage of an Uber app. I used the "SWRevealViewController" to create the the side menu.

The following was what I tried:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.MapView.showsUserLocation = true

        self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()

menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = 

#selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
                view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


       self.MapView.isZoomEnabled = false;
            self.MapView.isScrollEnabled = false;
            self.MapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

The side menu comes out when the menuButton is pressed, but I cannot seem to be able to "drag" it to collapse it.Im thinking that the map's function(such as zoom, moving, etc) needs to be disabled somehow so it doesn't interfere with the "dragging" of the side menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) instead of `SWRevealViewController`

It will be working fine in any case your case is very simple pan gesture is using for map already so when your trying to use for menu its not working.

For Implementation of `SlideMenuControllerSwift` you need to do like following,

Add pod in your pod file,

```
pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'
```

After successfull install add two View controllers `YourMapVC` and `LeftMenuVC` and in your `AppDelegate` file add the following method,

```
func createMenu() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let yourMapVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourMapVC") as! YourMapVC
        let leftMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuVC") as! LeftMenuVC

        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourMapVC)

        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftMenuVC, rightMenuViewController: UIViewController())
        slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

After that call above method in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate` like below,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.createMenu()
        return true
    }
```

For Adding the Menu Button In `UINavigationBar` place following extension anywhere in your project.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func setupNagivationBar() {

        self.removeNavigationBarItem()
        self.setNavigationBarItem()

    }

    func setNavigationBarItem() {

        self.slideMenuController()?.removeLeftGestures()
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeRightGestures()


        self.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "icon_menu")!)
        self.slideMenuController()?.addLeftGestures()
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeRightGestures()
        self.slideMenuController()?.closeRight()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
    }



    func removeNavigationBarItem() {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeLeftGestures()
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeRightGestures()
    }


}
```

and call the `setupNagivationBar()` method inside your `YourMapVC` `viewDidLoad` method.

```
class YourMapVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupNagivationBar()

    }

}
```

Also you need to put the icon_menu image in your project.

Below is the Result you can see in screenshots.

[image: YourMapVC]

[image: LeftMenuVC]

Following is the Tutorial Link,
https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! Do you happen to have a sample code or direct me to a tutorial on this?

Comment: I have updated the answer also mentioned the link of tutorial @rengineer

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! I tried that but cannot seem to get it to work correctly. Do you think I can take a look at the project code that is in the above screen shots?  My email is : rnh96821117@gmail.com. Thanks for your help. Sorry for the inconvenience.